# Is there a function that would allow me to output current index of an element in json array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.4

I have the following sample Postgres SQL query.

```
SELECT name, json_array_elements(myjson)->>'id' id FROM
(SELECT 'Dingsda'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 100}'::json, '{"id" : 200}'::json) myjson
  UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Dingsbums'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 101}'::json, '{"id" : 201}'::json, '{"id" : 301}'::json) myjson
) t;
```

It outputs the following table.

```
+-----------+-----+
|   name    | id  |
+-----------+-----+
| Dingsda   | 100 |
| Dingsda   | 200 |
| Dingsbums | 101 |
| Dingsbums | 201 |
+-----------+-----+
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is to put a third column at the end that would contain the index of the element of the json array starting with 0 and so on. The result should look as follows.

```
+-----------+-----+-------+
|   name    | id  | index |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| Dingsda   | 100 |     0 |
| Dingsda   | 200 |     1 |
| Dingsbums | 101 |     0 |
| Dingsbums | 201 |     1 |
| Dingsbums | 301 |     2 |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Unfortunately I have not found a function that would help me. I tried to experiment with `row_number() OVER` but it seems to return strange results when a `json` typed column is involved.

Is there any function that would support this rather simple requirement?

### EDIT

The Mureinik's answer is helpful, however I want to be able to preserve the original sequence of the elements in json. In this example the sequence is lost. I think it is not deterministic.

```
SELECT name, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY 1)
FROM (SELECT name, JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(myjson)->>'id' id 
      FROM   (SELECT 'Dingsda'::text AS name, JSON_BUILD_ARRAY('{"id" : 100}'::json, '{"id" : 200}'::json, '{"id" : 300}'::json, '{"id" : 400}'::json) myjson
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Dingsbums'::text AS name, JSON_BUILD_ARRAY('{"id" : 101}'::json, '{"id" : 201}'::json, '{"id" : 301}'::json) myjson
         ) t
      ) s;
```

```
+-----------+-----+-------+
|   name    | id  | index |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| Dingsbums | 101 |     1 |
| Dingsbums | 201 |     2 |
| Dingsbums | 301 |     3 |
| Dingsda   | 100 |     1 |
| Dingsda   | 400 |     2 |
| Dingsda   | 200 |     3 |
| Dingsda   | 300 |     4 |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use a set-returning function (such as `json_array_elements()`) in the `SELECT` clause, unless you know exacly what you're doing. It'll just make things harder for you.

You can use the [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) clause of table functions (9.4+), which is intended for exactly your problem:

```
SELECT name, elem->>'id' id, "index"
FROM (SELECT 'Dingsda'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 100}'::json, '{"id" : 200}'::json) myjson
        UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Dingsbums'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 101}'::json, '{"id" : 201}'::json, '{"id" : 301}'::json) myjson) t,
     json_array_elements(t.myjson) WITH ORDINALITY e(elem, "index");
```

You can also use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) with `json_array_length()`, but `WITH ORDINALITY` is way more simple.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. Neither of the keyword `WITH ORDINALITY`. Very helpful! It also does preserve the sequence of my array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using `row_number` seems to be the right approach. You just need to wrap this query with another one to produce the row's number:

```
SELECT name, id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY 1)
FROM (SELECT name, JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(myjson)->>'id' id 
      FROM   (SELECT 'Dingsda'::text AS name, JSON_BUILD_ARRAY('{"id" : 100}'::json, '{"id" : 200}'::json) myjson
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'Dingsbums'::text AS name, JSON_BUILD_ARRAY('{"id" : 101}'::json, '{"id" : 201}'::json, '{"id" : 301}'::json) myjson
             ) t
      ) s;
```

Comment: Hi, this is helpful but in some cases the sequence is lost here. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join (recommended anyway) and `with ordinality`

```
SELECT name, x.element ->> 'id' as id, x.idx
FROM (
  SELECT 'Dingsda'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 100}'::json, '{"id" : 200}'::json) myjson
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dingsbums'::text AS name, json_build_array('{"id" : 101}'::json, '{"id" : 201}'::json, '{"id" : 301}'::json) myjson
) t
  cross join lateral json_array_elements(myjson) with ordinality as x(element, idx)
```